# datatables serverside processing with unknown number of rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Does datatables have any support for [server-side](http://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/examples/initialisation/server-side_processing.html) retrieving of data where the **rocordsTotal** count is ***not known in advance***?

We have data for which the query to get the total-count is almost as expensive as just querying all records. It would be need if there was a way to let datatables know that the **recordsTotal** count is not known. Such functionality isn't documented. Is it supported?

**Update 1:**
I think i didn't completely explained my problem and tried to ask an abstract version. I am using datatables.net/extensions/scroller plugin and it works with **ajax** option. If i use a large number for **recordsTotal** then the user can scroll to the button and i have no data to show there. The same thing is true with pagination, user can click on a page number that might not exist.

Comment: What kind of database do you work with? What kind of table / view is it, since it takes so long to get total count of rows?

Comment: @davidkonrad https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Counting

Comment: DataTable's basic server-side example - http://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/examples/initialisation/simple.html - doesn't seem to be using the TotalRecords. Do you have a jsfiddle of your actual setup?

Comment: jjbskir: The basic server-side example doesn't show any server-side code, which is why you don't see anything about it in that example. The "TotalRecords" he's referring to is likely the "recordsTotal" field in the object Datatables expects to be returned from the server.

Comment: Amin, I've updated my answer to elaborate a little more on the solution I'm proposing. I realized I left out a few critical details please reread. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming by "TotalRecords" you mean "recordsTotal" field in the object the server returns to datatables. You could just take a count for the next N pages that meet your search criteria, assign this value to "recordsFiltered" and "recordsTotal", and not render the total records count via the "dom" option: http://datatables.net/reference/option/dom *note the i component*. It isn't built-in functionality, but it is a doable workaround for not knowing the table count in advance.

Doing this will let Datatables know that you have at least N more pages to look through via the "recordsFiltered" field so pagination works correctly. This way Datatables doesn't necessarily need to know exactly how many total records you have in order to work.

You could also use the footerCallback option to customize your data summary below the table. Take a look here: https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html

Also, since you mentioned in a comment that you're using postgresql, I don't know if this is relevant to you or not (I've never used postgresql) https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Count_estimate

Comment: Thank you very much, the **i** option solves one of my problems. and using **footer_callback** is really useful. i didn't completely explained my problem in the original question, i tried to ask an abstract version. i am using https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/ plugin and it works with **ajax** option. if i use a large number for **recordsTotal** then the user can scroll to the button and i have no data to show there. the same thing is true with pagination, the user can click on a page number that might not exist.

Comment: If you have an idea for other option, i will be really appreciated, otherwise i will wait two more days and then accept your answer. thanks :)

Comment: Don't use an arbitrary large number. Take a count of just the page you're on and the next few pages just to make sure they exist, and then set both recordsTotal and recordsFiltered to that count. This should be faster than taking a full count of the table.

Comment: Amin, I think you don't understand my answer correctly. My answer addresses your updated concern- your question was understood even in abstract form the first time.